# Using sqlite in VB.NET Metro App

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am struggling for days to adjust my VB.NET metro app to uses SQLite database.

I have metro app that targets Win 8
then I added reference to:

```
.NET for Windows Store apps
Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Package
SQLite for Windows Runtime
```

Still no way to work with database this way.
When I try to add:

```
Imports SQLite
 Using db = New SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbpath)
```

- its not being recognized

What EXACTLY do I need to setup SQlite for VB.NET Metro App ?
Is there any sample project that I can download and start with ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added sqlite-net from nuget?